# Sidekiq Stats are stuck at 0 even if jobs are performed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, task, jobs, sidekiq, monitor

I have a Rails 5 app and I've just installed the Sidekiq gem as a backend for Rails ActiveJob.

My problem is that even if I manage to enqueue a job and complete it, all Sidekiq stats are stuck at zero.

What I have done:

1. Run the following commands:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install redis
$ brew services start redis
```

2. Added the following gemfiles:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-failures', '~> 1.0'
```

3. Run the following commands:

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle binstub sidekiq
```

4. Modified the following file:

```
# config/application.rb
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
end
```

5. Modified the routes to get the monitor (without authentification for now)

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  require "sidekiq/web"
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

6. Added the following config file:

```
# config/sidekiq.yml
:concurrency: 3
:timeout: 60
:verbose: true
:queues:  # Queue priority: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options
  - default
  - mailers
```

7. Launched the rails server, then sidekick, then rails console in 3 different tabs:

```
$ rails s
$ sidekiq
$ rails c
```

8.Tried to use `perform_later` on the following test job:

```
class TestCreateSnippetJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  def perform(shop_domain = "shoes-lab.myshopify.com")
    puts "hello job"
    sleep 30
  end
end
```

```
$ TestCreateSnippetJob.perform_later
```

And here is what I get :

```
[1] pry(main)> TestCreateSnippetJob.perform_later
Enqueued TestCreateSnippetJob (Job ID: bc5bf654-09f5-4c77-95d8-8258a560525d) to Async(urgent)
=> #<TestCreateSnippetJob:0x00007feec140e9c8
 @arguments=[],
 @executions=0,
 @job_id="bc5bf654-09f5-4c77-95d8-8258a560525d",
 @priority=nil,
 @provider_job_id="a59c111d-ebe1-43b2-bf23-55748b660af8",
 @queue_name="urgent">
[2] pry(main)> Performing TestCreateSnippetJob (Job ID: bc5bf654-09f5-4c77-95d8-8258a560525d) from Async(urgent)
hello job
Performed TestCreateSnippetJob (Job ID: bc5bf654-09f5-4c77-95d8-8258a560525d) from Async(urgent) in 30038.27ms
```

The problem I have is the following: the monitor root/sidekiq doesn't show any "processed" job, even if TestCreateSnippetJob is done. Every stat is stuck at 0.

And furthemore, when I try to launch this job from a task, nothing happens, the job is not executed, unlike when I try to launch it directly from the console.

```
namespace :test do
  desc "TODO"
  task test: :environment do
    TestCreateSnippetJob.perform_later
    puts "Task done"
  end
end
```

Do you guys have any idea of what I could have done wrong?

#### EDIT

It seems Rails (v5.2.3) overrides ActiveJob queue_adapter. As mentioned by @Mike Perham, my log shows that I ame using the :async adapter, not :sidekiq even if I added the `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` line to `config/application.rb.`

So I tried to add `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` to `config/environments/development.rb` and sidekiq works fine this time, the jobs are enqueued to Sidekiq.

However, is it a good practice do this in this way?

PS: it only works when I keep the `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` line in `config/application.rb.` **and** `config/environments/development.rb`.

#### EDIT 2

In both cases, whether I add or not the `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` line in `config/environments/development.rb` in addition to the same line in `config/application.rb.`, the command `$ Rails.application.config.active_job_queue_adapter` returns `:sidekiq`

Answer (score 1):

Your log shows that you are using the :async adapter, not :sidekiq.

```
Enqueued TestCreateSnippetJob (Job ID: bc5bf654...) to Async(urgent)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Following what you have highlighted, I edited my initial post to try something else, which worked. But I don't think it's the best solution, it may not be a good practice... What do you think?